# This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have built a sql job to update some value in table regarding to the condition in the where clause as below:

```
 Update c set isLoaded = 0 , LoadingState = 'L', isSent = 0
    from Container c
    where c.isloaded = 1 and DATEDIFF(second,  dateadd(HOUR, c.LoadingInterval,c.entrydate),  getdate()) / 3600.0 between c.LoadingInterval and (c.LoadingInterval + 2)
```

But the following error appeared when I try to run this script:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateContainersStatistcs, Line
>   9 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression. The statement has been terminated.

The reason is because of trigger created on the table.
I disabled this trigger and everything is working well 
the trigger script is as below:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateContainersStatistcs]
ON [dbo].[Container]
After Update
AS
BEGIN
declare  @DayDateNow as int 
set   @DayDateNow = (select count( DayDate) From ContainersStatstics AS ConStc where DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())) and ConStc.ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ) )
if @DayDateNow>0 

  BEGIN 
  if UPDATE(LoadingState)
      BEGIN
          if( (select i.LoadingState from inserted as i) = 'E')
            begin 
                if ((select i.LoadingState from inserted as i)=(select LoadingState from Container as Cont where Cont.RFID = (select d.RFID from deleted as d)))
                    begin
                          update ContainersStatstics
                          set EmptyContainersCount= (select EmptyContainersCount From ContainersStatstics as ConStc where (DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())) and ConStc.ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ))) + 1
                          , ContainersCount=(select Count(Id) from Container where ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ))
                          where  ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ) and DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate()))
                      end
            end
        else
            begin
                if (select Count(EmptyContainersCount) From ContainersStatstics) > 0
                        begin
                                if ((select i.LoadingState from inserted as i)=(select LoadingState from Container as Cont where Cont.RFID = (select d.RFID from deleted as d)))
                                    begin
                                            update ContainersStatstics
                                            set EmptyContainersCount= (select EmptyContainersCount From ContainersStatstics as ConStc where (DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())) and ConStc.ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ))) - 1
                                            , ContainersCount=(select Count(Id) from Container where ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ))
                                            where  ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ) and  DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate()))
                                    end
                            end
             end
      end
      else if UPDATE(WashingStatus)
      BEGIN
      if( (select i.WashingStatus from inserted as i) = 'E')
                BEGIN
                        if ((select i.WashingStatus from inserted as i)=(select WashingStatus from Container as Cont where Cont.RFID = (select d.RFID from deleted as d)))
                                BEGIN
                                        update ContainersStatstics
                                              set WashedContainersCount= (select WashedContainersCount From ContainersStatstics as ConStc where ( DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())) )and ConStc.ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con )) + 1
                                              , ContainersCount=(select Count(Id) from Container where ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ))
                                               where ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ) and DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate()))
                                    end
                end
      else
                Begin
                            if (select Count(EmptyContainersCount) From ContainersStatstics) > 0
                                    begin
                                            if ((select i.WashingStatus from inserted as i)=(select WashingStatus from Container as Cont where Cont.RFID = (select d.RFID from deleted as d)))
                                                    begin
                                                              update ContainersStatstics
                                                              set WashedContainersCount= (select WashedContainersCount From ContainersStatstics as ConStc where ( DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())) )and ConStc.ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con )) - 1,
                                                              ContainersCount=(select Count(Id) from Container where ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ))
                                                               where ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con ) and DayDate= (SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate()))
                                                       end
                                    end
                end
      end
  end
else
  BEGIN 
   if UPDATE(LoadingState)
   BEGIN
    if ((select i.LoadingState from inserted as i)= 'E')
            begin 
              insert into  ContainersStatstics
             (EmptyContainersCount ,ContractorId,DayDate,ContainersCount,WashedContainersCount)values   (1,(select x.ContractorId from inserted x),(SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())),(select Count(Id) from Container where ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con )),0) 
            end
   END

    else if UPDATE(WashingStatus)
    begin 
    if ((select i.WashingStatus from inserted as i)= 'E')
        BEGIN
         insert into  ContainersStatstics
             (EmptyContainersCount ,ContractorId,DayDate,ContainersCount,WashedContainersCount)values   (0,(select x.ContractorId from inserted x),(SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())),(select Count(Id) from Container where ContractorId =(Select Con.ContractorId from inserted as Con )),1) 

        end
    end
  end
END
```

Comment: This query looks fine as written.  Please look for another update that has a subquery like `where key = (select key from othertable)`.

Comment: Now I know the reason there is a trigger on this table but i don't know what shall I do to fix this issue; I can't disable it

Comment: If there is a trigger like that - then I fear your only approach is making sure the update only runs on one row at the time because it seems the trigger is poorly made and cannot handle multiple rows.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the trigger code. that way someone can help you re-write it to fix this error.

Comment: this trigger contains a lot of code. It's not going to be easy to fix without an explanation on it's purpose and the structure of the relevant tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query is totally correct but the reason of the error was a trigger created on the same table.

I disabled the trigger on the table and now everything is working well